# Append a plus sign before positive numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to append a plus sign before numbers. I am already using format specifier:

```
"{0:+03f}".format(x)
```

And I've heard about those two as well, but I don't know how to use them:

```
"%+d" or "%+f"
```

My problem with the first one is the fact that the number after format is in float type.

For example, I am making a small program to calculate quadratic function and I am not satisfied with output like this:

```
f(x) =  2x^2+2.000x-4.000000
```

Those zeros are making it looks weird.

If not above, is there any solution to get rid of zeros when there is nothing, but only zeros after the dot?

Comment: Of course it would be a float, the `f` in `"{0:+03f}"` stands for `float`.

Comment: I rollbacked your latest edit, follow up / chameleon questions are against the rules. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377469/is-it-acceptable-to-rollback-a-question-to-remove-an-additional-question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps `%g` is what you're looking for?

```
>>> '%+g' % 2.
'+2'
>>> '%+g' % 2.1
'+2.1'
>>> '%+g' % 2.10001
'+2.10001'
```

The exact definition of `%g` is as follows:

> General format. For a given precision p >= 1, this rounds the number
>   to p significant digits and then formats the result in either
>   fixed-point format or in scientific notation, depending on its
>   magnitude.
>
> The precise rules are as follows: suppose that the result formatted
>   with presentation type 'e' and precision p-1 would have exponent exp.
>   Then if -4 <= exp < p, the number is formatted with presentation type
>   'f' and precision p-1-exp. Otherwise, the number is formatted with
>   presentation type 'e' and precision p-1. In both cases insignificant
>   trailing zeros are removed from the significand, and the decimal point
>   is also removed if there are no remaining digits following it.
>
> Positive and negative infinity, positive and negative zero, and nans,
>   are formatted as inf, -inf, 0, -0 and nan respectively, regardless of
>   the precision.
>
> A precision of 0 is treated as equivalent to a precision of 1. The
>   default precision is 6.

([source](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html).)

Similarly with `format()`:

```
>>> '{0:+g}'.format(2.)
'+2'
>>> '{0:+g}'.format(2.1)
'+2.1'
>>> '{0:+g}'.format(2.1001)
'+2.1001'
```

Comment: but, but, this is old style formatting. any alternative with `format` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Yes, exactly the same thing. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

`%+g` works but uses (very) old-style formatting. Python has evolved to provide 2 modern formatting methods:

New style formatting:

```
>>> "{0:+g}".format(2.00001)
'+2.00001'
>>> "{0:+g}".format(-2.00001)
'-2.00001'
>>> "{0:+g}".format(2)
'+2'
```

and with python 3.6+ f-strings:

```
>>> value = 2
>>> f"{value:+g}"
'+2'
>>> value = -2.00001
>>> f"{value:+g}"
'-2.00001'
>>> value = 2.00001
>>> f"{value:+g}"
'+2.00001'
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but I've got new problem. This code gives me negative number even when q1 is already negative - str((f"{q1:-g}")). Why isn't it formatting the number q1 (for example q1 = -2) to --2 which should be just 2?

Comment: you should not add follow up questions like this. Since you're using 3.6 formatting why not doing `f"{-q1:+g}"` or take absolute value `f"{abs(q1):+g}")`